# Counting Primitive Operations in Java

Tags: java, algorithm, big-o

I'm trying to count primitive operations in Java and have stumbled across this. I don't know why retrieving the array only accounts for one count instead of two.

I have this piece of code:

```
 arrayExample[j] = arrayExample[j] + 1; // 2 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
```

For some reason, we count reading `j` twice, assigning once, adding once and accessing array once.

Why is it that accessing the array is not done twice here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Well wouldn't you need to read `j` and retrieve index `j` from the array so that would still be 2 operations. So by my calculation this would be 4 operations for retrieving `j` and retrieving the index of the array at point `j` and another 2 operations for adding and assigning?..

Comment: You already counted "reading j twice" as two operations, so why would you count four array operations?

Comment: Because you need to read what the value of `j` is and then retrieve index `j` from the array which are two operations? Since we're doing this twice, we have 4 operations. If you count the adding and assigning that would be 6 total.

Comment: Where is the source where you found this?

Comment: Just from my lectures

Comment: When you assign a new value in the array at index i, you don't need to read the value that was there before. So there is no reason to count two reads from the array here.

Comment: Now I see, thanks Kaya.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By "accessing the array" they mean reading the value there. The assignment to the array is a different kind of array access, it's just been counted as an assignment instead of as an array access.

Without a more formal definition of what counts as a "basic operation", this is a bit of an ill-defined problem anyway. We might ask why loading the constant 1 doesn't count as a basic operation. (Or you could be pedantic and check whether the JVM has an "increment" bytecode operation that doesn't require loading 1 as a constant. It does.) Or you might ask why it makes sense to just count the number of basic operations of all kinds, when different basic operations (e.g. integer addition vs. floating-point division) have different running times.

For Big O analysis, what matters is that the number of basic operations here is a constant, which doesn't depend on the size of any input to the algorithm. Whether you count it as 4, 5 or 6 basic operations doesn't matter since anyway it's O(1) basic operations.

Comment: *FYI:* I count it as [8 primitive operations](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58922980/5221149). Bytecode is about as primitive as you can get with Java. --- Up-voted for the comparison with Big-O.

Comment: Indeed, though for the purpose of algorithm analysis, "basic operation" is usually defined in a more abstract way that doesn't depend on the implementation details of a particular language. I suspect the lecturer either glossed over this, or gave a list of what they count as basic operations in an earlier lecture.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't define "primitive operation", so let's use the primitive operations that the Java compiler generates, i.e. the bytecode:

*Java source*

```
int[] arrayExample = {};
int j = 0;

arrayExample[j] = arrayExample[j] + 1;
```

*Generated bytecode*

```
 0: iconst_0             // arrayExample = new int[0]
 1: newarray     int
 3: astore_1

 4: iconst_0             // j = 0
 5: istore_2

 6: aload_1              // Prepare arrayExample[j] for "store"
 7: iload_2
 8: aload_1              // Load arrayExample[j]
 9: iload_2
10: iaload
11: iconst_1             // + 1
12: iadd
13: iastore              // Store as prepared
```

So, **8** "primitive operations".

Comment: This isn't a very satisfactory answer because it certainly defines "basic operation" in a different way than it's defined by the lecturer who provided the example which the question is asking about. For the purposes of algorithm analysis, "basic operation" is usually defined more abstractly. But I'm upvoting because it is a *useful* answer that gives a direct view on what the machine actually does to execute the code. I think it's worth adding that the three "extra" instructions are two `aload_1` which load the array reference from `arrayExample`, and one `iconst_1` which loads the constant 1.

Comment: Speaking as an educator, it may be only for historical reasons that "basic operation" is defined so abstractly in textbooks and lectures; or perhaps lecturers assume that an abstract definition will be easier to understand than bytecode instructions are. But there's a case to be made that counting bytecode instructions is better because it positions the question as one which has an objective, non-debatable answer, and it also means students can use a disassembler to investigate for themselves. I think this raises an interesting point about how to teach algorithm analysis.